# Interface inheritance is public inheritance, while implementation inheritance is private inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Is there any notion of " Interface inheritance is public inheritance, while implementation inheritance is private inheritance" in java?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774204/difference-between-interface-inheritance-and-implementation-inheritance) post.

Answer (score 0):

I read the post you linked. In this post, Péter Török states about *Private Inheritance* the following:

> However, if B privately inherits from A, B is-implemented-in-terms-of A: only the implementation of A is inherited, not its interface. Thus (references/pointers to) B objects can not be used in places where A objects are expected.

I don't think there is such thing in Java as *Private Inheritance*, at least in the terms expressed above.

So, after reading the post and considering that in Java:

- *Interface Inheritance* is related to interfaces and classes implementing this interfaces, and
- *Implementation Inheritance* is related to class specialization

I think it is not possible the case where you create a Class `B` that implements an Interface `A` or extends a Class `A`, and this Class `B` couldn't be used as `A`.