# Why does Instant.EPOCH and Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH) return different results?

Tags: java, time, java-time

Using java.time's Instant and java.sql's Timestamp, why do these:

```
System.out.println("epoch: " + Instant.EPOCH);
System.out.println("timestamp: " + Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH));
```

produce different results:

```
epoch: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
timestamp: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.0
```

Comment: they don't, it's just the formatting that is different.

Comment: Related: [Java - Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset)

Answer (score 1):

The `Timestamp` class injects the JVM‘s current default time zone. One of many reasons why you should *never use these legacy date-time classes*. Use only their replacement, the *java.time* classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on these wretched date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `Timestamp` with their unanimous adoption of JSR 310.

Your JVM’s current default time zone on the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC was using an offset-from-UTC of one hour ahead. Hence the 1 AM display, adding one hour to the same simultaneous moment with a time of 00:00 seen in places such as Iceland whose offset from UTC  on that date at that time was zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Another problem with that output from `Timestamp#toString` is that it neglects to indicate its time zone or offset-from-UTC. In contrast, the `java.time.Instant#toString` method puts a `Z` on the end to indicate, per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

The `Instant` class represents a moment in UTC, always UTC, an offset of zero. So no such confusion and ambiguity as with `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does Instant.EPOCH and Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH) return
> different results?

Echoing [Stultuske's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68035411/why-does-instant-epoch-and-timestamp-frominstant-epoch-return-different-result/68041424#comment120250309_68035411):

> they don't, it's just the formatting that is different.

### Let's see how

Given below is the hierarchy of [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

```
java.lang.Object
    java.util.Date
        java.sql.Timestamp
```

On the same page of the documentation, you will find the following information:

> The inheritance relationship between `Timestamp` and `java.util.Date`
> really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

The **implementation inheritance** is a way of reusing the code of the superclass in a subclass and **type inheritance** is a way of specializing (subclassing) a supertype for a specific implementation<sup>**</sup>.

The purpose of creating `java.sql.Timestamp` has been summarized in the following line on the same page of the documentation:

> A thin wrapper around `java.util.Date` that allows the JDBC API to
> identify this as an `SQL TIMESTAMP` value.

So, *do not expect `java.sql.Timestamp` to be much different from `java.util.Date`.*

### About `java.util.Date`:

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of ***milliseconds*** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or UTC). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
```

On the other hand, An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc).

### Putting all in a demo:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Instant:   " + Instant.EPOCH);
        System.out.println("Timestamp: " + epochMilliFormatted());
    }

    public static String epochMilliFormatted() {
        Date date = new Date(Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH).getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        return sdf.format(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Instant:   1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
Timestamp: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/dkJJCm)

**Note:** The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>. Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

** To learn more about the implementation inheritance and the type inheritance, check the following links:

1. [Multiple Inheritance of State, Implementation, and Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html)
2. [implementation inheritance vs type inheritance](https://coderanch.com/t/477939/java/implementation-inheritance-type-inheritance)
3. [difference between interface inheritance and implementation inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3774204/10819573)